# I need to display custom separate by days for my output like below

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need to display
group by days for my output like below

12/05/2018
name email phone

13/05/2018
name email phone

```
<?php
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sample") or mysqli_connect_error();
        $result_per_page = 10;
        $calculation_data_query = "SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY date DESC";
        $run_calculation = mysqli_query($con, $calculation_data_query);


        $table_data = "SELECT * FROM `users` LIMIT 0,10";

        $table_data_query = mysqli_query($con, $table_data); 

        $number_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($run_calculation);
        $number_of_row_per_page =ceil($number_of_rows/$result_per_page);
        while($row_value= mysqli_fetch_array($table_data_query)){
        ?><tr>

                <td id="user_id"><?php echo $row_value['id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row_value['name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row_value['email']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row_value['phone']; ?></td>
                <td>
                <?php
}


        ?>
```

Comment: Don't think we want to achieve the same thing

Comment: @WilsonEllis, if you feel this is not a duplicate, then please redact your post and clarify further. Review this documentation for further assistance: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can go with :

```
<?php
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sample") or mysqli_connect_error();
        $result_per_page = 10;
        $calculation_data_query = "SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY date DESC";
        $run_calculation = mysqli_query($con, $calculation_data_query);


        $table_data = "SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,10";

        $table_data_query = mysqli_query($con, $table_data); 

        $number_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($run_calculation);
        $number_of_row_per_page =ceil($number_of_rows/$result_per_page);
        $tmpDate = '';
        while($row_value= mysqli_fetch_array($table_data_query)){
            if(empty($tmpDate) || $tmpDate != $row_value['date']){
            ?>
                <tr><td colspan="4"><?= $row_value['date'] ?></td></tr>
            <?php
            }
                <tr>
                <td id="user_id"><?php echo $row_value['id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row_value['name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row_value['email']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row_value['phone']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
           $tmpDate = $row_value['date'];
}


        ?>
```

Date might need some format before display though..

Comment: there's an error on line "if(empty($tmpDate) || $tmpDate != $row_value['date']{"

Comment: Lacked a closing ")". My bad.